Resolving AngularJS Unknown Provider Error in horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api
I'm encountering an issue with AngularJS where I'm receiving the [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider error. The error message points to horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.novaExtensionsProvider as the unknown provider that AngularJS cannot resolve. This is causing problems in my application, particularly with the launchInstanceModel.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.novaExtensionsProvider <- horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api.novaExtensions <- launchInstanceModel

I've defined the horizon.app.core.openstack-service-api module, but I suspect there might be an issue with how providers are registered or loaded within this module.
Dependency Injection: novaExtensionsProvider seems to be crucial for novaExtensions, which is then needed by launchInstanceModel. However, AngularJS is unable to find novaExtensionsProvider
How to resolve the [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider error? Any additional debugging techniques or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
